# Creating JSON inside a loop in .Net

Tags: json, vb.net, loops

I'm trying to get this code to work dynamically but I can't.
I need to add more lines, placing this code inside a `for` loop.

My actual working code is:

```
Dim objAtrib as object = New With {Key .attributes = {
    New With {Key .id = "MODEL", Key .value_name = "RT1"},
    New With {Key .id = "BRAND", Key .value_name = "SAM"}
}}
```

I need some like this:

```
For i as integer = 0 to r.count
  Dim objAtrib As Object = New With {Key .attributes = {
      New With {Key .id = i, Key .value_name = i}
  }}
Next
```

Any help will be appreciated.
The JSON result should be like this:

```
{
   "attributes":[
      {
         "id":"Z",
         "value_name":"0"
      },
      {
         "id":"A",
         "value_name":"1"
      },
      {
         "id":"B",
         "value_name":"2"
      },
      {
         "id":"C",
         "value_name":"3"
      },
      {
         "id":"D",
         "value_name":"4"
      },
      {
         "id":"F",
         "value_name":"5"
      },
      {
         "id":"G",
         "value_name":"6"
      }
   ]
}
```

The class Model is:

```
 Public Class Attributes
        Public Property id As String
        Public Property value_name As String
    End Class

    Public Class RootObjectAtributosPublicar
        Public Property attributes As Attributes()
    End Class
```

This doesn't work:

```
For m As Integer = 0 To grid.RowCount
    Dim id As String = ""
    Dim valor As String = ""

    id = grid.GetRowCellValue(m, "id")
    valor = grid.GetRowCellValue(m, "Valor")

    objAtrib.attributes(m).id = id
    objAtrib.attributes(m).value_name = valor
 Next
```

Comment: Well do you have a source of data? What is it? Yes, But is not the same every time. sometimes the array (Attributes) could have 1 value, or 10 values.

Attributes is an array, inside we have id and value_name

Comment: thanks again jimi, done.

Comment: The Origin of the Data is a GridView Control, i take the id and value_name values and i must add to the Object.  i dont know how to make it.

Comment: i Have Added new lines of Codes on Original Post. My problem is convert the data to the Object.

Comment: you have no idea how much you have helped me.
I've spent all day with this. I am really grateful to you. I will take your comments into account. Please tell me how I can value your help.
Thanks Again.

Comment: All right, I made a sum of all comments. Both `Json.Net` and `System.Text.Json` are considered, if you're using another type of serializer, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The Model built to describe as serialize the to JSON the source of data appeers correct, since it matches the desired JSON result.
A small chanage is required to simplify the procedure: change the array in the Root object to a `List(Of Attributes)`, so new objects can be added to the collection is a more efficient way:

```
Public Class RootObjectAtributosPublicar
    Public Property attributes As List(Of Attributes)
End Class

Public Class Attributes
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property value_name As String
End Class
```

The, just loop the objects in the data source (here, the data is taken from a Control - I suggest to use the source of data used to fill the Control, if possible), create a new `Attributes` object per iteration and fill it with the data read from the source, then add the new object to the List defined in the Root object:

```
Dim root = new RootObjectAtributosPublicar() 
root.attributes = new List(Of Attributes)

For m As Integer = 0 To grid.RowCount
   Dim attr = new Attributes() 

   attr.id = grid.GetRowCellValue(m, "id") 
   attr.value_name = grid.GetRowCellValue(m, "Valor") 
   root.attributes.Add(attr) 
Next
```

Now, to generate a JSON, you can serialize the `RootObjectAtributosPublicar` object:

With `Json.Net`:

```
Dim json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root)
```

With `System.Text.Json`:

```
Dim json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(root)
```

The result is of course the same:

```
{
   "attributes":[
      {
         "id":"MODEL",
         "value_name":"RT1"
      },
      {
         "id":"BRAND",
         "value_name":"SAM"
      }
   ]
}
```